# How do I resolve a Part::partd: message

Tags: core-language

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];

Sn = {1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 48, 64};
tSt = {1, 2, 3, 4};
nS = 8;
npt = 4;
err = 0.01;
Et = 0.01802;
S0 = 1;
k1 = 60;
k2 = 240;
k3 = 15;

Model1 = 
  First[
    NDSolve[{
      Eu'[t] == -k1 Eu[t] S[t] + k2 ES[t] + k3 ES[t],
      ES'[t] == k1 Eu[t] S[t] - (k2 + k3) ES[t],
      S'[t] == -k1 Eu[t] S[t] + k2 ES[t],
      P'[t] == k3 ES[t],
      S[0] == S0,
      ES[0] == 0,
      P[0] == 0,
      Eu[0] == Et}, 
      {Eu, ES, S, P}, {t, 0, 4}, 
      MaxSteps -> 100000, 
      PrecisionGoal -> Infinity]];

Plot1 = 
  Plot[P[t] /. Model1, {t, 0, 20}, PlotRange -> {{0, 4}, {0, 0.25}}]

ClearAll[S0];

n = 1;
While[n <= nS, 
  S0 = Sn[[n]];
  m = 1;
  While[m <= npt, 
    St = tSt[[m]];
    k1 = 60;
    k2 = 240;
    k3 = 15;
    Et = 0.01802;
    Model1 = 
      First[
        NDSolve[{
          Eu'[t] == -k1 Eu[t] S[t] + k2 ES[t] + k3 ES[t],
          ES'[t] == k1 Eu[t] S[t] - (k2 + k3) ES[t],
          S'[t] == -k1 Eu[t] S[t] + k2 ES[t],
          P'[t] == k3 ES[t],
          S[0] == S0,
          ES[0] == 0,
          P[0] == 0,
          Eu[0] == Et}, 
          {Eu, ES, S, P}, 
          {t, 0, 4}, 
          MaxSteps -> 100000, 
          PrecisionGoal -> Infinity]];
    Evaluate[ToExpression["tabdata" <> ToString[n] <> ToString[m]]] = 
      {S0, St, (P[npt[[m]]] /. Model1) RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[1, err]]};
    m++];
  n++];
```

> Part::partd: Part specification 4[[1]] is longer than depth of object. >>

Comment: Why indeed are you trying to extract the part of a number?

Comment: `npt[[m]]`: `npt` is a number not a list, so you cannot take `Part`s of `npt`.

Comment: @march has clearly identified the source of the error, but in order for us to help you fix it, could you clarify what you are trying to do with your code? As it is, I cannot follow your intentions, so I am unable to help you.

Comment: Before someone else says it, it is wise to not use single capital letters for function names or variables , as these may clash with built-in functions.

Comment: I have severely edited this question to remove a great deal of extraneous code.

Answer (score 1):

The code line

```
Evaluate[ToExpression["tabdata" <> ToString[n] <> ToString[m]]] = 
  {S0, St, (P[npt[[m]]] /. Model1) RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[1, err]]};
```

is causing your difficulties. My recommended fix is

```
Sn = {1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 48, 64};
tSt = {1, 2, 3, 4};
nS = 8;
npt = 4;
err = 0.01;

ClearAll[tabdata];
n = 1;
While[n <= nS,
  S0 = Sn[[n]];
  m = 1;
  While[m <= npt,
    St = tSt[[m]];
    k1 = 60;
    k2 = 240;
    k3 = 15;
    Et = 0.01802;
    Model1 = First[
      NDSolve[{
        Eu'[t] == -k1 Eu[t] S[t] + k2 ES[t] + k3 ES[t], 
        ES'[t] == k1 Eu[t] S[t] - (k2 + k3) ES[t], 
        S'[t] == -k1 Eu[t] S[t] + k2 ES[t], P'[t] == k3 ES[t], 
        S[0] == S0, ES[0] == 0, P[0] == 0, Eu[0] == Et}, 
        {Eu, ES, S, P}, {t, 0, 4}]];
    tabdata[n, m] = 
      {S0, St, (P[m] /. Model1) RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[1, err]]};
    m++];
  n++]
```

A fairly nice way to display the results of running the above code is

```
TableForm[TableForm /@ Array[tabdata, {nS, npt}]]
```

[image: table]